# How to measure the effect of each covariate in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictor, importance, basis-function

I have a GLM model with two variables (Z1 and Z2). I have also used some basis functions to estimate these variables. In other words, Z1 is substituted by 10 basis functions and Z2 with 12 basis functions. Hence GLM gives me (10+12+1) coefficients (the last one is to account for a constant term). What I am interested is to know what's the effect of each variable Z1 and Z2. I don't want to know the effect of each of those basis functions.

Is there a way to answer this question in GLM model?

Comment: You have constructed a model in which there are 22 effects.  In what sense, then, do you intend us to interpret "effect of each variable"?  Could you articulate what that is supposed to mean?

Comment: Let's say Z1= C1.x1+C2.x2+...+ C10.x10 and Z2= D1.y1+D2.y2+...+ D12.y12. {C1,C2.....C10, D1,D2,...D12} are the coefficients that GLM computes and {x1,x2.....x10, y1,y2,...y12} are the values of the basis functions. What I am interested is the influence of Z1 and Z2 and not the effect of each basis functions separately.

Comment: If $R$ denotes your response variable, one way to assess the influence of $Z_1$ is to compute the conditional expectation $E(R|Z_1)$ by marginalizing over $Z_2$, and vice-versa for the influence of $Z_2$.

Comment: Mina, that still begs the question of what you mean by "influence" and "effect."  That could refer to an awful lot of things!  Could you elaborate on what you're trying to ask?

Comment: By influence I mean which variable is more important to describe the response variable. I am wondering if we can even ask a following question: how much of the response variable is explained by Z1 and how much is explained by Z2? It would be good if I can get an answer in percentage. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MossMurderer How can I then convert the expectation to the measurement of influence?

Comment: The expectation $E(R|Z_1)$, viewed as a function of $Z_1$, essentially tells you how $R$ depends on $Z_1$, which I consider the "influence" of $Z_1$. If you're interested in a single number, may be you can compute the $R^2$ value between the true response $R$ and the model-predicted response $E(R|Z_1)$.

Comment: If you showed what these functions are, that would help. From your description they could be linear functions but certainly do not have to be linear.